# Implementing Bluetooth Dial-up networking(DUN) profile so that mobile device can be used as a wireless dial-up modem for Internet access?

Tags: android, bluetooth, dial-up

I am trying to write an application which will provide the DUN service on Android so it could be used for Internet access on PC or Laptop. This page [BlueTooth DUN](https://www.bluetooth.org/Building/HowTechnologyWorks/ProfilesAndProtocols/DUN.htm) says 'application' will play the role of DUN-GW (Gateway).

I guess, the responsibility of the DUN-GW service would be to take data request from Android (initiated by Data Terminal), download the data and provide it to Android for forwarding. Also, it must add an entry, Dial-up networking, to the Bluetooth services provided by Android device (but how?)... And everything else would be taken care of by the OS.

My queries are:

1. How to tell the Android that my application provides BlueTooth DUN-GW service/profile?
2. How would the app get notified that Data Terminal(PC) is trying to connect to the internet through the DUN-GW service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved in newer phones.